# use Session cookies with adonis & react

Tags: reactjs, authentication, session, cookies, adonis.js

I'm having trouble understanding how session cookies work. I have an Adonisjs Api and a React app.
In my login / Register components, I fetch the data with post request and credentials set to true. Everything work fine and the adonis-session cookie is set in the browser.
But, after that, I want to be redirected to the homepage and fetch users' posts but I get 401 unauthorized response.

Can someone help me understand what I need to do? How can I check if the user is logged in with this adonis-session token? Use the context API?

Comment: Is the API and the homepage on the same domain and are both the same protocol? e.g. both https

Comment: Also `credentials` should be `'include'` instead of `true`. And ensure this is also set on the request to get the users post api.

Comment: @Privitar Yes, api and react app are both on localhost. Credentials are 'include'.